# Cannot access to web server, but can ssh to it; iptables not installed

Tags: apache-httpd

I have apache2 running on an Armbian 5.25 box and I can connect to apache on port 80 from within my network, but not externally.  I can connect to the box using ssh externally.  I have forwarded ports 21, 22, and 80 in my router. Since the ssh is working I assume my port forwarding of port 80 is also working, so I am trying to figure out why I can't reach apache externally.  Here is my output from `netstat -ntl` showing that it is listening on port 80:

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.119:5000      0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8112            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:21              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::21                   :::*                    LISTEN
```

I don't have iptables installed or firewall-cmd, as both return command not found (even when running as root).

Comment: As a side note, `command not found` could be a path problem.

Comment: It looks like it's listening on 80, but with tcp6 only.

Comment: Could be a path problem, true, but iptables is not installed in /sbin or /bin.  Anywhere else I should look?

Comment: Based on reading other threads it sounds like other people have reported that netstat only shows ip6 but listens on both ip4 and ip6, so I wasn't concerned about that.  Should I be?

Comment: I changed "Listen 80" to "Listen 0.0.0.0:80" and now netstat shows that apache is listening on tcp instead of tcp6, but I still cannot connect (after restarting apache).

Comment: can you telnet to localhost on port 80?
`telnet localhost 80` 
Also, if you create an index.html in your web directory, can you `wget http://localhost/index.html` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ISP may be blocking 80.  Try using port 8080 on your router and forward to port 80 on your Armbian.

Comment: I can't check this until I get home, but looking it up I see that Optimum does block port 80, so that is likely the problem here.  Thanks for pointing that out.